# How to call data from Node.js file to JADE such that it appears dynamically and does not reloads or refreshes the whole page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am attempting a minified version of a e-commerce type website where I make client register and login using database. After login, the client is "welcomed" with his "username" displayed from template. Now I want to show products categorised like: mobile and books. In each product category, further there are different elements of products, like for mobile: m1, m2 ,m3... etc. I want to call these products dynamically in the JADE template instead of reloading another template altogether.

**//the server file**

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var fs=require('fs');
var path=require('path');
var jade=require('jade');

function checkLogin(userid,pwd,res){
  var db= mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb");
  var userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    "uid":String, "pwd":String
  });

  var user= mongoose.model("test1",userSchema);
  console.log("UserID "+userid+" Password "+pwd+" UserObject "+user);
  user.find({"uid":userid,"pwd":pwd}, function(error,docs){
    if(error){
      console.log("!!!Error!!!", error);
    }
    if(docs && docs.length>0){
      console.log("DOCS", docs);
      console.log(typeof docs);
      var path2= path.join(__dirname, '/sample.jade');
      fs.readFile(path2,'utf-8', function(error, source){
        var template= jade.compile(source);
        data={"username":docs[0].uid,
        products:[{"category":"Mobile","image":"mobile.png",img:["/images/1.png","/images/2.png","/images/3.png"]},
                  {"category":"Books","image":"books.png",img:["/images/b1.jpg","/images/b2.jpg","/images/b3.jpg"]}]};
        //console.log("UID ",data.username);
        var html= template(data);
        res.end(html);
        //console.log(html);
      });
    }
    else{
      res.end("Invalid User or Password");
    }
  });

}

module.exports=checkLogin;
```

**//sample.jade**

```
doctype
html(lang='en')
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title Shopping Cart
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css')  

  body
    h1 Welcome to Shopping Cart #{username}
    h4 Select a product below and start buying!

    each product in products
      li= product.category
      a(href="/category?type=product.category")
        img(src=product.image, width="150", height="150")
        //- after the user selects a product category,
        //- I want to show more products in that specific category here


    div#footer 
      p.
        <i class="fa fa-code"></i> with <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> | <i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> 2016
```

Comment: You mean you want to make an ajax request and either build the html dynamically after a json response or return HTML and insert it into the DOM? Or something else?

Comment: No, not ajax request nor DOM. There is a way, when you declare data as object that is being passed to while rendering Jade file such that Jade reads 'keys' from object and put its value in the template page shown to the client.
Like for every different user who has registered, on login, the page shows the message "Welcome" #{username} this username is taken from the "userid" a field described in db.